# How to print out the index of the split?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-fold

So I have some data of 8 columns and many rows and I want to perform a K-Fold split with 5 splits. I've done that, but what I want to do now is for every split, print out the split number it is on. See the code for a better explanation.

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=5) #Define the split - into 5 folds 

#Define empty arrays for each technique
kf_train = []
kf_test = []

#Iterate through each feature in 
for kf_train, kf_test in kf.split(df):
    print('Split # ????')
    for col_name, col_data in df.iteritems():
        print('Feature: ', col_name)
        print('Mean: ', np.mean(col_data))
        print('Standard Deviation: ', np.std(col_data))
        print('\n')
```

So where it says `print('Split # ????')` is where I'm having the issue. What should I write in order to get the following output:

```
Split #1
Feature: XXX
Mean: 3.3
Std: 3.3

Split #2
etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an `enumerate` should solve your problem:

```
for i, (kf_train, kf_test) in enumerate(kf.split(df)):
    print('Split #{}'.format(i))
    for col_name, col_data in df.iteritems():
        print('Feature: ', col_name)
        print('Mean: ', np.mean(col_data))
        print('Standard Deviation: ', np.std(col_data))
        print('\n')
```

For reference: [docs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` that gives you the index plus the value

```
# Iterate through each feature in 
for idx, kf_vals in enumerate(kf.split(df)):
    print('Split #%s' % idx)
    kf_train, kf_test = kf_vals
    for col_name, col_data in df.iteritems():
        print('Feature: ', col_name)
        print('Mean: ', np.mean(col_data))
        print('Standard Deviation: ', np.std(col_data))
        print('\n')
```